# Is it possible to run out of ID numbers in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress, every post (entry, product, etc) has a unique ID number. As the sites grow up in content, I've realized that the ID numbers are increasing constantly.

I'm guessing that the number of posts available can be quite high (or so I hope!) but I'm asking out of curiosity. Is there actual limit of posts you can have?

What happens when a post is deleted? Do the system fill up the gaps in some way?

Is it OK to leave the posts there to grow old like the wine or is it a good practice to clean up every now and then if you have too many?

Comment: No, there is no limit. Clean up is up to you. It's probably more manageable if you do clean up your posts. When a post is deleted, that post id is not reused. That would be a nightmare for the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wp_post.ID` column is a `unsigned bigint`, which (in MySQL, the database used by Wordpress) can store values from 0 to 18446744073709551615 ((2^64)-1). So in theory, that is the maximum number of posts.

Now, there are other tables that get multiple rows for each post and those tables have the same maximum (because their `ID` column is also a `unsigned bigint`). For example "posts meta" and comments. Because of that, you'll run into problems a bit sooner, but even if `posts_meta` gets 1000 rows for each post, you'll still have about 1844674407370955 posts you can make before you run into this limit.

Now, the question wasn't "is there a maximum amount of posts", the question is "is it possible to run out of IDs". I would call creating 1844674407370955 posts impossible, so: no.

Comment: I wouldn't say "impossible", just highly unlikely for a normal WordPress website.